# PHP Outputing JSON file

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I am trying to achieve the following JSON format:

```
function generatePieTicket(data) {
$('#piecharts').highcharts({
.....
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Ticket Share by Team',
            data: [
                ['Technical', 45.0],
                ['Logistic', 26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Others',
                    y: 28.2,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
            ]
        }]
```

so that i could later call it asynchronously like this:

```
function generatePieTicket(data) {
$('#piecharts').highcharts({
....
series: data
```

This is my attempt to generate the desired JSON

```
function getPieData(){
    $data = array(
        array(
            'type' => 'pie',
            'name' => 'Sample Pie Chart',
            'data' => array(
                array('Technical', 45.0),
                array('Logistics', 26.8)
            ),
            '' => array(
                'name' => 'others',
                'y' => 28.2,
                'sliced' => 'true',
                'selected' => 'true'
            )
        )
    );

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

and this is the result

```
[
    {
        "type": "pie",
        "name": "Sample Pie Chart",
        "data": [
            [
                "Technical",
                45
            ],
            [
                "Logistics",
                26.8
            ]
        ],
        "": {
            "name": "others",
            "y": 28.2,
            "sliced": "true",
            "selected": "true"
        }
    }
]
```

I am confused as to how to do this part:

```
data: [
    ['Technical', 45.0],
    ['Logistic', 26.8],
    {
        name: 'Others',
        y: 28.2,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
    },
]
```

Could anyone tell me how to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner array belongs to `data`.

```
function getPieData(){
    $data = array(
        array(
            'type' => 'pie',
            'name' => 'Sample Pie Chart',
            'data' => array(
                array('Technical', 45.0),
                array('Logistics', 26.8),
                array(
                    'name' => 'others',
                    'y' => 28.2,
                    'sliced' => 'true',
                    'selected' => 'true',
                ),
            )
        )
    );

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Darren he beat you. I just have to vote & accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just had your array out the wrong way, try this:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'type' => 'pie',
        'name' => 'Sample Pie Chart',
        'data' => array(
            array('Technical', 45.0),
            array('Logistics', 26.8),
            array(
                'name' => 'others',
                'y' => 28.2,
                'sliced' => 'true',
                'selected' => 'true'
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

That will give you what you want.

---

**Explanation**

This array:

```
array(
'name' => 'others',
 'y' => 28.2,
 'sliced' => 'true',
 'selected' => 'true'
)
```

belongs within the `data` array :)